# How do you define a variable for mysqli_connect?

Tags: php, mysql

I am following an example on W3C for a simple database connection using PHP and MYSQL however it is coming up with two errors which I don't understand due to on W3C that is how they do it and theirs do not error.

**Error 1**

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShoutIt\database.php on line 3

**Error 2**

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShoutIt\database.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ShoutIt\index.php(1): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShoutIt\database.php on line 3

**index.php file**

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Shout It !</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>SHOUT IT! Shoutbox</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="shouts">
                <ul>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="input">
                <form method="post" action="process.php">
                    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
                    <br/>
                    <input class="shout-btn" type="submit" name="submit"value="Shout It Out !" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**database.php file**

```
> <?php //Connect to MySQL $con =
> $mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Passwordaaa","shoutit");
> 
> //Test Connection if(mysqli_connect_errno()){     echo 'Failed to connect
> to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error(); }
```

Comment: above is the code in "database.php file" or something missing ?

Comment: `$mysqli_connect` should be `$con = mysqli_connect()` its not a variable its a function call and you need the resulted data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just **correcting your code** ?
(removing the chevrons, replacing `$mysqli_connect` by `mysqli_connect`, etc.)

Take a look at [PHP syntax documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php).

```
<?php
//Connect to MySQL
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Passwordaaa","shoutit");

//Test Connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: damn it thanks always something small that I miss when staring at it for a while

Answer (score 5):

Procedural style that you are using

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Passwordaaa","shoutit");

if (!$con) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
?>
```

if you want to use Object oriented style

```
<?php
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Passwordaaa","shoutit");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
    }
    ?>
```

for more details you should go through the PHP Manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php

Comment: it is a bad idea to use error supression (`@`) in these instances (as in for a beginner learning the code). Please remove the at symbol.

Comment: Thanks @Martin for your suggestion, I removed '@'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
 $mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Passwordaaa","shoutit");
```

By:

```
 mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Passwordaaa","shoutit");
```

Answer (score 0):

go through http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```